# Оптимизация приложения.

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

Здравствуйте. Приложение для мобильных телефонов на `JavaScript`.
Есть множество окон и, соответственно, файлов `JavaScript`. Все эти файлы объявлены на странице `index.html`. Приложение на `Sencha Touch Ext`. И вот вопрос: *Нормально ли это, или не лучше бы все файлы разбросать по разным страницам, чтобы подгружались необходимые скрипты последовательно (и соответственно, пользователь бы перемещался со страницы на страницу)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал что-то типа фронт контроллера который подключал бы необходимые скрипты, либо просто слил бы все в 1о файлище( ну и сжал бы его естестно )

По поводу сжатия - [почитайте здесь](http://polezniy.com/2011/02/07/kak-szhat-javascript-na-99-6/)